# Content-Type in GET method not getting populated

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-http

Setting Content-Type for GET method is not getting populated using Apache Camel-Http component.

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
```

Whereas the same is working when using POST method.

Understood that there is no body for method GET. A strange thing is, if body is set to empty string("") Content-Type is being passed but the method type also changes to POST.

```
exchange.getIn().setBody("");
```

2.13.1 is the Camel version that i am currently using. Tried with the latest versions too, still the same. Is there something that i am missing.

Service mandates to pass Content-Type.

Answer (score 0):

In the Camel source there is a test for this kind of scenario: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http4/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpProducerContentTypeTest.java

In both the test cases the body need to be set. You should see this in camel-http4:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http4/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/http4/HttpProducer.java#L482-L582

and camel-http too:

https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-http/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/http/HttpProducer.java#L447-L506

If you decide to use Http4/http component then you'll need to set a body.

There is also this very old discussion on nabble:
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Http4-Set-Header-Content-Type-not-passing-through-to-the-HTTP-Request-td5746414.html

Comment: Thanks for the details. I have already gone through the discussion above and as mentioned in it, using apache-cxfrs is not an option for me. We consume lot of services using apache-http component. How to handle such scenarios wherein GET type requires Content-Type too.

Comment: There is no other way than setting a body.

Comment: If body is set, method type is changed to POST. Tried setting an empty string "".

Comment: The component is not developed for this. It's not possible to set content type on a GET request.

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs! Will look at the possibility changing to Camel-cxfrs.